# Dropdownlist for flex mobile. Programmatically detect where the user presses and set the selectedItem

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to use a drop down list on Flex Mobile. Now, I know technically you aren't supposed to use it for Flex Mobile projects. Adobe discourages its use but my application needs it. Here is what I have tried-

```
    <s:DropDownList id="industry" width="160" height="35"
                                    change="onDropDownChange(event)"  click="onDropDownClick(event)"/>



protected function onDropDownIndexChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
                {   //removeEventListener(event:IndexChangeEvent);
                    industry.selectedIndex =industry.selectedItem;
                }

protected function onDropDownClick(event:Event):void {
                    industry.openDropDown();
                    //industry.selectedItem=industry.selectedIndex ;
                    industry.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE, onDropDownIndexChange );
                }

protected function onDropDownChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {


                trace(industry.selectedIndex);
                trace(industry.selectedItem);
                event.target.listData = industry.selectedItem;
}
```

I have not been able to register a click on the drop down menu. And I don't know how to detect a touch(or click) event on the menu to set it. Thanks for reading and all your help.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding Self Indulgent; use the [Flextras Mobile DropDownList](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=21).  It is free for production use (but you have to pay if you want source or help).

Here is our [web based sample](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/MobileDropDownList/).  We have a few different renderers and skins.  To make the DropDown look like a standard mobile drop down we recommend using the Radio Button Renderer, and our Pop Up Skin 2.

The default DropDown List for Flex has issues with touch interaction, especially when clicking in the drop down.  To create your own version, you'll have to work around these issues.  We created a bunch of custom skins, and added a few extra properties/styles.